# Detecting multiple PageUp/PageDown key presses

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keypress

I have a NumericUpDown control in WinForms. The Up/Down arrow keys increase/decrease the value by 1. I want to map the PageUp/PageDown keys for larger increments.

The `Control.KeyPress` event does not get fired with the PageUp/PageDown keys and if I use the `Control.KeyUp/Control.KeyDown` events, the combination fires only once even if the user keeps the keys pressed for a while.

How could I trap multiple PageUp/PageDown keys presses during long key presses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange to say, but I cannot reproduce this issue. I have a new winform instance, numericUpDown control with default property` values and KeyDown event handler works perfectly with long key press:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown)
            numericUpDown1.Value -= 10;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
            numericUpDown1.Value += 10;
    }
```

Can you provide your code in the event handlers?
/*Sorry, I know Im not supposed to ask for clarification in the answer, but I can`t write comments.*/

Comment: Ah, my implementation only manipulated the value if both KeyDown and KeyUp match the same key. Your example does work.